On lacunary series connected with prime number theory
Consider the following lacunary sum with parameter $x$:
$$S(x)=\sum_{n=5}^{\infty}\sin^2\left(\frac{x\Gamma(n)}{n}\right).$$
As we can see for $x=\frac{\pi}{2}$
the sum becomes$$\sum_p\cos^2\left(\frac{π}{2p}\right)$$
where $p$ runs through all primes.


What are some non trivial properties of $S(x)$?




Can we at least prove infinitude of primes (at $x=\pi/2$) from this ?



Forgive my ignorance, but is $\Gamma$ the Gamma function (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function) here? If so then isn't $\Gamma(n) = (n - 1)!$?

@JosephHarrison yes

Is it obvious that you get $\sum_p \cos^2(\pi/2p)$ when you take $x = \pi/2$? Do you have a reference?

@JosephHarrison I think for target audience for this sort of things on mathoverflow is pretty elementary!
